# how to get a specific array in codeigniter's active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

for example if i have a bunch of data stored in an active record like so

model

```
 function get_cdj($id){
    return $this->db->select()->from("news_dj")->where("news_id",$id)->get();       
}
```

controller

```
 public function news_edit($id)
{
    $data['cdj'] = $this->newscms_model->get_cdj($id);
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('admin/news_edit');
}
```

and the variable i want to print is...

```
$cdj->id
```

and i want to get the third variable inside it

is there a way to make it look similar to this -

```
$data[3]
```

?

---

is there a way to control which row i want to print using codeigniter's active record?

just like php's native

```
 <?php echo $data['insert the row number you want to get here']; ?>
 ie: $data[3]
```

thanks

Comment: your questions are not clear yet.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get ?

Comment: why dont you just match that row id in query ?? why onlythird ? plz make clear your requirement to us.

Comment: i would like to put a variable inside the array so it would look like this <?php foreach($name as $n){echo $n->name; echo $data[$i]; $i++;} ?>. where $data[$i] would be changed into something similar to codeigniter's active record

Comment: Do you want to fetch news by its Id and show that data in news_edit form ?

Comment: yes im trying to echo the contents of my $data variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

**Model**

```
function get_cdj($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where("news_id",$id);
    return $this->db->get("news_dj")->row();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function news_edit($id)
{
    $data['cdj'] = $this->newscms_model->get_cdj($id);
    $this->load->view('admin/news_edit',$data);
}
```

**news_edit (view)**
You can access your content like this

```
echo $cdj->dbfieldname;
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you needed?

```
function get_cdj($id){
    $return = $this->db->get_where('news_dj',array('news_id' => $id));
    if($return->num_rows())
        return $return->result();
    else return false;
}

$data = $this->newscms_model->get_cdj($id);

var_dump($data[3]);
```